# How to concatanate diagonal matrices in Eigen

Tags: matrix, eigen, diagonal

I have a set of diagonal matrices say

```
a1=(2 0
    0 3)

a2=(3 0
    0 5)
```

How do I create a third matrix which is a=a1 :a2 where : is the concat operator i,e

```
a=(2 0 3 0
   0 3 0 5)
```

I created the `a1` and `a2` matrices using the `DiagonalMatrix` class

```
DiagonalMatrix<double, 2> a1(2, 3);
DiagonalMatrix<double, 2> a2(3, 5);
```

I am unable to use the block operator as it is not implmented in the DiagonalMatrix class.

Also I am unable to visualize  the matrix as

```
cout << a1 << endl;
```

gives me compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create a dense (or sparse) matrix:

```
Matrix<double, 2, 4> result;
```

Second, you can assign the two diagonal matrices to the two left and right columns, respectively.

```
result.leftCols(2) = a1;
result.rightCols(2) = a2;
```

You can visualize your diagonal matrix by converting it to a dense matrix:

```
cout << a1.toDenseMatrix() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the diagonals into the diagonal of the target:

```
DiagonalMatrix<double,Dynamic> a3(4);
a3.diagonal() << a1.diagonal(), a2.diagonal();
```

Comment: No I do not want to concatenate unto the diagonals of the target matrix. I wanted to arrange them one next to the other as above. Also I have problem in visualizing the matrix on the screen.  If I use cout<<a3 <<endl; I get a compilation error stating /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2753:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
read.cpp:119:7: note:   ‘Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<double, 2>’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
 cout<<a1<<endl; which I am unable to understand